# Integrate fadeIn/fadeOut to a content switching script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an image collage/patchwork. I'm using masonry.js to lay out the content how I need, and a script I found on this very site to change the div contents randomly (between two images).

However, I would like a simple way to animate this image switch, but my javascript/jquery knowledge is very limited.

Below is the complete code for my site:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #container {
                width: 350px;
                height: 420px;
                border: solid 1px #000;
            }
            .item {
                width: 105px;
                height: 105px;
                margin: 0;
                float: left;
            }
            .item_2 {
                width: 245px;
                height: 105px;
                margin: 0;
                float: left;
            }
            .item_3 {
                width: 245px;
                height: 210px;
                margin: 0;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var logSwitch =[
                "<img src='apps/TRA-100.gif' />",
                "<img src='apps/logistics.gif' />",
            ];

            setInterval(function() {
                var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * logSwitch.length);
                if (i == logSwitch.length) --i;
                $("#logistics").html(logSwitch[i]);
            }, 5 * 1000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
          <div class="item_3"><img src="apps/auto.gif" /></div>
          <div class="item"><div id="logistics"><img src="apps/TRA-100.gif" /></div></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="apps/marine.gif" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="apps/its.gif" /></div>
          <div class="item_2"><img src="apps/Entertain.gif" /></div>
          <div class="item_2"><img src="apps/meteor.gif" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="apps/aviation.gif" /></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $container = $('#container');
            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $container.masonry({

                    columnWidth : 300
                );
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone advise we what direction to head in? This fiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/jWcLz/1/) looks quite simple, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you replace the HTML within `#logistics`, but nothing is done to make it fade.  The way the demo jsfiddle you linked to works is by calling `fadeOut()` on the parent element and when that's done calling a `fadeIn()` function on that same element, while also giving it new content.

Here's how you can do the same thing in your code:

Replace...

```
$("#logistics").html(logSwitch[i]);
```

...with...

```
$('#logistics').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).html(logSwitch[i]).fadeIn(500);
});
```

---

**Edit:** if you don't want the content to be switched randomly, don't make it random!  Instead, set `i` outside of `setInterval()` and then just change `i` within it.

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
     i++;
     if (i == logSwitch.length) {
          i = 0;
     }
     $('#logistics').fadeOut(500, function() {
          $(this).html(logSwitch[i]).fadeIn(500);
     });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Is there any way I can change the random aspect, too, so that it always switches from one to the other? The fade effects look unnecessary when it stays on the same image.

Or set it so that the fade effect only happens when the image WILL change? I'm asking a lot, I know...

Comment: @MatthewPeckham see updated answer; I think that should take care of it, but let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Works like a charm. Appreciated.